# Parse.com Android SDK OKHTTP interceptor

Tags: android, parse-platform, okhttp

With version 1.15 of the Parse Android SDK, the previous network interceptor model was removed in favor of OKHTTP interceptors.  However, I can't find any information on how to add an interceptor.  Creating an interceptor class is fine, but then what do I do with it?  The Parse.Configuration.Builder class, which is where that used to be done, doesn't seem to have a method to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nowhere to directly pass in an interceptor, but `Parse.Configuration.Builder` has a method `clientBuilder`.  You make a `OkHttpClient.Builder` however you want, for example with a `HttpLoggingInterceptor`, and pass it to `clientBuilder`.